# Handling all exceptions AND Failed Messages in a BizTalk 2010 solution

Tags: exception, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a BizTalk 2010 solution that polls a database table, retrieves unprocessed records, does a transform with a map and call a 3rd party service. The happy path is working.

Here is the workflow:

1. Receive Location/Port from GetUnprocessedCustomers stored procedure: Poll SQL Server 2008 with WCF-SQL adapter by calling stored proc that returns unprocessed customers (WHERE IsProcessed = 0)
2. SendPort to 3rd Party web service: Filtered to ReceivePortName ==  with an outbound map to convert message returned from the above mentioned stored proc to service schema
3. SendPort to UpdateIsProcessed stored proc: Filtered to MessageType ==  with an outbound map to convert service response to stored procedure call that will update IsProcessed = 1.

I would like to catch the following possible exceptions, create a message with exception info and call an internal exception handling service.

1. Database or stored procedure is not accessible.
2. 3rd party service is not accessible.

I was able to handle number 2 above by enabling Failed Message routing. Thanks to [Greg.Forsythe](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/c7328eec-6b66-409c-82af-788920bf64b4).

My question is:
How can I create a generic solution that will capture all exceptions and send exception info (such as exception datetime, message, stack trace etc.) to an internal service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get an answer on the [BizTalk General Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/5cce589b-c741-44a2-bb3f-16836cb8fb8b). The short answer is "There is no way to catch all exceptions". Hit the link for some options.